# Looking for examples on Airflow GCSToS3Operator. Thanks

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to send file from GCS bucket to S3 bucket using Airflow. I came across this article https://medium.com/apache-airflow/generic-airflow-transfers-made-easy-5fe8e5e7d2c2 but looking for specific code implementations and examples which also explains the requirements for this. I am a newbie to Airflow and GCP.

Answer (score 0):

Astronomer is a good place to start with . see the [doc for GCSToS3Operator](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/amazon/modules/gcstos3operator).

You can get dependencies, explanation on each variable and links to examples